# Submitting form when there are 2 forms

Tags: html, forms

How do I send the contents of the form with out sending the contents of my other form on the same page? For example

```
<form class="form" method="get" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" value="hi" name="forminput1">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<form class="form" method="get" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" value="byebye" name="forminput2">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

page.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['forminput1'])) {
    //some code
}
if (isset($_GET['forminput2'])) {
    //some code
}
```

Whenever I submit form #2, I end up submitting form #1.

Comment: Maybe because they both have the same action?

Comment: depends on what your php looks like and you left that important bit out. So, php comes into the picture *when?* You tagged as such but nothing to support the question with.

Comment: I noticed the edit with the removed php tag; that's even worse. How can you expect anyone to solve this? You have 2 forms, so? What's that got to do with sending the same value? Which input did you press and so on? Your question is still unclear, far as I'm concerned. Well, I'm out of here. Ask the people who gave you answers; I tried to help by sticking around here, but I obviously wasted my time, and yours also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , Sorry if I have wasted your time. I removed the php tag because I realized I didn't put any of my php. I have 2 forms. When I click submit, it submits both form's data when I just want the data from the form I submitted. I specifically named the inputs and got it in my php file. However, it still sends the other form's data and that also gets through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given any of your inputs a name attribute. Without a `name="somename"` attribute the browser will not pass anything back on the GET or POST.

If you add a name attribute like this

```
<form class="form" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" value="hi" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
</form>
<form class="form" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" value="byebye" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
</form>
```

It will suddenly start to work as you expect.

If you want to make both forms unique you can add a different name to the submit buttons.

```
<form class="form" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" value="hi" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send_form1">
</form>
<form class="form" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" value="byebye" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send_form2">
</form>
```

and then in your PHP, you will be able to differentiate between which form (button) is being submitted like this

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['send_form1'])) {
    // User sent form1
}

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['send_form2'])) {
    // User sent form2
}
```

Comment: sure hope you won't get chased down a rabbit hole here. OP just removed the php tag. I don't see what good that did. It made it worse, IMHO.

Comment: I feel like a challenge tonight. Couple of pints inside me and I am ready for anything @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yeah I noticed about the pints LOL! You went a bit too fast on the `$GET`'s and missing brackets ;-) looks like I'm the dedicated driver tonight.

Comment: Thats `designate` and thanks. Dont want the pot head picksies getting grabbed by the fuzz do we _Ouch_ ___Hic___

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using the same action....Forms are independent